# Data from intent to webview

Tags: android, cordova

I thought it'd be possible to send data from an activity to a phonegap-webview using the sql-lite database. It's not working, unless you use a phonegap-plugin.
I checked the android-api and I guess a json-file can't be accessed from the webview either.

So, how can I send data from the activity to the webview/web-app.

Comment: when you start your app than what is first perform to execute Activity or phonegap webview.

Comment: I load the webview this way:
    super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());